# convert set to map of string with count

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

My original data is stream of string like

```
correctname
abc,def,ghi,jol
abc
def,ghi
zzzzzzzzzz
myname
pppppppppp
jkl
```

Converting it set:

```
{correct}
{abc, def,ghi,jkl}
{abc}
{def,ghi}
{invalid}
{correct}
{invalid}
{jkl}
```

I have some Stream.map(…) which is returning me above result

`Map<String,Long> answer = Stream.map(...).collect(groupingby??)`

Now I want to collect it (collect or map or groupingby) and return result as Map such that my answer should be

Map>
{correct: 2
invalid: 2
others: 8}

Comment: I'm confused. What does the `Long` represent? *How* are you mapping your sets to `Map<String, Long>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to `flatMap` each set to the strings that are in it. Once you've done that, you can use `map` to transform the values to the values you're interested in and count them. E.g.:

```
Set<String> allowed = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("correct", "invalid"));
Map<String, Long> result = 
    values.flatMap(Set::stream)
          .map(s -> allowed.contains(s) ? s : "other")
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                         Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for this:

```
Map<String, Long> answer = sets.stream()
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                s -> s.matches("invalid|correct") ? s : "others",
                Collectors.counting()));
```